# Parity violating metrics

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, parity

Is there are an example of a parity-violating metric? If so, how do they look like? Are Einstien equations parity invariant? What does it mean for a manifold or a metric to be parity invariant?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? In standard GR parity is conserved, which is independent of the metric.

Comment: @Eletie I wish to see how parity invariance holds in GR. Can you write a proof?

Comment: This follows almost immediately, just think about how the transformations would work in GR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove parity invariance of a set of equations:

1. First decide how each term in each equation would change under parity inversion. E.g. vectors change sign, pseudo-vectors do not, etc.
2. Replace each term by what it would be under parity-inversion.
3. Find out if the resulting equations are precisely the same as the ones you started with.

Tensor notation makes this pretty quick in the case of GR. You mainly need to think about the stress-energy tensor.